# How to enable C++11 in FlexeLint

Tags: c++11, pc-lint

Does anyone know how to enable C++11 support in Gimpel flexelint?

To achieve the same as the option `-std=c++11` in the GCC compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it on with `-A(C++11)` flag

The generic way to turn on a wanted standard is: `-A(C++year)`